# Uri.parse give the null value

Tags: java, android, null

I have successfully fetch data from another database and can print it on a TextView. But when I try to pass the data into `Uri.pase()` like this below it gives me null.

```
public void gotosite(View v) {
    s = responseTextView.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+s+""));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

this method give the TextView print of my expected data. I wanna set the data at Uri.parse()

```
public  void  setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + json.getString("adUrl");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.responseTextView.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: `Log.d("nullcheck", s);` is a good start

Comment: Problem is solved, Thanks @stealthjong

Comment: how can get a specific record from all data... I don't want to use where criteria in my sql. I want to get specific just one record  from JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare String s globally to use in different methods. Make sure that you are running `setTextToTextView` method first and then you are running `gotosite()` method  as `String s=""`.

```
String s; // declare this globally

public  void  setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + json.getString("adUrl");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    this.responseTextView.setText(s);

}

public void gotosite(View v) {

   s=responseTextView.getText().toString(); // either use this or you can now use string s directly 

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+s+""));
        startActivity(i);

    }
```